# Number of surjective functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $|X| = n,|Y| = 3$.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function where $|X| = n$ and $|Y| = 3$.

I think it is $n(n-1)(n-2)$ since for the first element in $Y$, I pick out of $n$ possible elements that map to this first element and so on.

Is this the correct line of thinking?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You'll have to use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Isn't the answer is $C(n,3)$.

Comment: @iamwhoiam how come I can't do it that way?

Comment: @DionelJaime no, there may be various elements in $X$ that map to the same element in $Y$.

Comment: Suppose $n = 4$, and you have the map $\{(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1)\}$. This is surjective. You haven't counted this case.

Comment: I'm going to attempt it by inclusion exclusion, but unfortunately I still can't see what's wrong with me picking elements for the first element of $Y$, second element of $Y$ and then the third element of $Y$.

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 Because you are missing out on the rest of the domain. Every $x \in X$ has to map to some element in $Y$. I don't think inclusion-exclusion would be the best approach, try reading about Stirling numbers of the second kind, that would be a way to go.

Comment: Right. I forgot the definition of a function that all elements in $X$ maps to something...  
I feel like then I'd multiply by 3^(n-3) but I feel like I'd overcount.

Comment: You would over count if you multiplied by $3^{n - 3}$.

Comment: @DionelJaime  The answer is not $\binom{n}{3}$ since each element of $X$ must be mapped to an element of $Y$.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so you write down $Y = \{y_1, y_2, y_3\}$ and you pick out an element $x_1$ of $X$ and you say that $f(x_1) = y_1$ and you pick out a second element, $x_2$ and you say that $f(x_2) = y_2$, and you pick a third and say $f(x_3) = y_3$. That's fine, you've defined $f$ on three values but what about the rest of $X$? How do you define $f$ on $X - \{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$? What if you have two elements of $X$, say $x_1$ and $x_1'$ such that $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_1') = y_1$, which one are you picking? How do you distinguish between them?

Answer (score 4):

$\sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i-1} \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}$ where $i$ of the $n$ elements of $X$ are mapped to $1$, $j$ of the remaining $n-i$ elements are mapped to $2$ and the remaining $n-i-j$ elements are mapped to $3$ and where $ Y= \{1, 2, 3\}$

---

Observe that this answer is equivalent to the answer by @N. F. Taussig as follows. 
$\begin {align}  
\sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i-1} \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}  
&= \sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i-1} \binom{n-i}{j}\\
&= \sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\binom{n}{i}(2^{n-i}-2)\\   
&= \sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}-2\sum _{i=1}^{n-2}\binom{n}{i}\\  
&= \sum _{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}-(1+2n+2^n)-2[\sum _{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}-(1+n+1)]\\  
&= 3^n - 3\times2^n +3 \end{align}$

Answer (score 4):

Trevor Gunn has explained why your approach leads to an incorrect answer.

Observe that if we did not have the restriction that $f: X \to Y$ is surjective, we would have three choices for the image of each of the $n$ elements of $X$, so there are $3^n$ functions $f: X \to Y$.  From these, we must exclude those in which there are fewer than three elements in the range.

There are $\binom{3}{k}$ ways to exclude $k$ of the $3$ elements in the codomain from the range and $(3 - k)^n$ ways to map the $n$ elements of $X$ to the remaining $3 - k$ elements in the codomain.  Hence, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of surjective functions $f:X \to Y$ is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{3} (-1)^k\binom{3}{k}(3 - k)^n = \binom{3}{0}3^n - \binom{3}{1}2^n + \binom{3}{2}1^n - \binom{3}{3}0^n = 3^n - 3 \cdot 2^n + 3$$

Comment: Thank you and thanks for everyone else that cleared my misunderstanding as well.  
To me this seems hard to picture: why we use Inclusion Exclusion principle. As in, I see that we count the total number of unrestricted functions. Then we take away the number of functions where we exclude one element in the range. And then the part with adding back the number of functions where we exclude two of the elements in range confuses me, i can't see where the over lap is

Comment: The three constant functions are each subtracted twice, once for each way of excluding one of the other two elements from the range.  Since we only wish to exclude them once, we must add them back.

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking about it, which ties into other areas which you may have studied or may study in the future, is that if $f:X\to Y$ is surjective then the inverse $f^{-1}$ creates a *set partition* of $X$ into $|Y|$ non-empty subsets, or an *equivalence relation* on $X$ with $|Y|$ equivalence classes.

In particular, the number of partitions of a set of $n$ into $k$ non-empty subsets is important enough to be named: a *Stirling number of the second kind*, commonly denoted ${n \brace k}$.

As Stephen Meskin pointed out in a comment, this isn't quite the full story: the correspondence between the parts of each partition and the elements of $|Y|$ allows for an arbitrary permutation, so the final answer is $|Y|! {|X| \brace |Y|}$

Further reading:

- [OEIS A008277](//oeis.org/A008277)
- [Wikipedia:Stirling number of the second kind](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
- [MathWorld:Stirling number of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html)

Comment: Each partition of $X$ can be obtained from $|Y|!$ different surjections. So the answer is NOT ${n \brace k}$ but $k!{n \brace k}$.

Comment: @Stephen, an excellent point. Thank you.